# Application load on Windows startup. then auto scale and position it?

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to load an application on start-up, then auto position and scale it?

I want an application which starts up with windows to be auto-scaled to 265 x 704 Pixels and position itself to the top left of the screen (X = 0, Y = 0)
I have been so close and tried several solutions.

**1. Auto Hotkey** (latest stable version): And the script below in the start-up
    folder(.AHK). Position but not scale works?

```
<code>Run, C:\Users\STRUCTURE\AppData\Local\Programs\Signage App\Signage.exe
WinWait, Signage.exe
WinMove, 0, 0, 256, 704</code>
```

**2. Windows Layout Manger:** Positions and scales via Hotkey not on
    startup! Perhaps I can make a .BAT file to start a program, wait for the 
    program to start-up, then apply hotkey? For example I tried this
    code below I found on Stackoverflow

```
<code>@start "" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" && exit
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF
@end
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("^{ENTER}");</code>
```

**3.** I also have tried **Sizer** App and **AutoSizer** App. Though the issue 
    is none of them will launch and auto do it on start-up, they all are
    hotkey based, once I think I got one of the solutions to work, however, it only worked sometimes, possibly because it
    applies the shortcut before the App I want positioned and scaled started
    up.

This is for LED signage screen that is specifically 256 by 704 pixels, the media player is FHD, so the LED screen can only see 704 by 256 of the FHD signal from the top left.

Comment: With AutoHotKey, try the answer at [move and resize a application autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48122633/9012170). Without setting a title, handle or what is available to direct `winmove` to the correct window, then you may be relying on chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**These two answers below actually worked.**

1. [launch, then move and resize an application on Windows startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049224/move-and-resize-a-application-autohotkey/48122633#48122633)

   I just had to delete the "f5::" at the top and chuck it in my
   startup folder. Thanks to michael_heath in the comments.
2. Also, **AutoSizer** works, I must have had something conflicting on the
   first try, as I did mess around with many things, after a clean-up it worked perfectly. [www.southbaypc.com/autosizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/autosizer/)